# How to pass a class member variable to another component angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, components

car.ts has "isNewCar" variable in "export class Car{}", and I need to export the "isNewCar" variable to another component carSale.ts which is in a different directory, and not in the same module. Do I have to add the car.ts template to the carSale.ts file and add the "isNewCar" as input?

edit: car.ts has export class Car{ isNewCar:boolean = false; } and car.ts is a component. carSale.ts is also a component but it is not in a same/shared module as car.ts I need carSale.ts, and eventually carSale.ng.html to get access to the isNewCar variable. So, can you tell me how I would use the viewChild decorator or anything else in carSale.ts to access that variable? I would ideally not want to make a shared module though but if I have to, I can.

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the `Car` class like,

```
 export class CarSale extends Car {
    
    ngOnInit(){
      this.isNewCar = true;
    }
 }
```

By extending the `Car` class, you will be able to access the `isNewCar` property from the `CarSale` class

Answer (score 1):

Need some more information about the use case. Is the car.ts a component or a model ?
If the car.ts is a model you should aggregate it in your carSale.ts component or, if really necesary, make it globaly available with a service.
If car.ts is a component with his own template, then you can acces the value with the output event emitter or by using a viewChild decorator.
There are other way to share variables but the above is the more common.

car.ts :

```
/*
* This is a POJO
*/
export class Car{
    isNew: boolean;
}
```

car-sale.component.ts :

```
export class CarSale {

    car: Car; // Car is aggregate into CarSale

    ngOnInit(){
        car = new Car();
        car.isNew = true;
    }

}
```

car-sale.component.html

```
<-- just use your car object like this --!>
<div *ngIf="car">Is the car new ? {{ car.isNew }}</div>
```

Comment: car.ts has
export class Car{
isNewCar:boolean = false;
}
and car.ts is a component. carSale.ts is also a component but it is not in a same/shared module as car.ts I need carSale.ts, and eventually carSale.ng.html to get access to the isNewCar variable. So, can you tell me how I would use the viewChild decorator or anything else in carSale.ts to access that variable? I would ideally not want to make a shared module though but if I have to, I can.
Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: First, your two components car.ts and carSale.ts are highly coupled and must be integrated into the same module. Second, your car.ts seems to be a domain model and must be used as a data structure (without any method in it). Finally, your carSale declare your car object and then you can use it in both your ts and your template.

Comment: I just edited my previous post. Hope this help. Have fun with angular ;)